# java.util.Arrays in Blackberry JDE v5.0 dev

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm trying to use

```
float f[] = new float[20] ;
java.util.Arrays.fill( f, 0.0f ) ;
```

but Eclipse is flagging the second line as `java.util.Arrays` cannot be resolved to a type.

What's going on here?  Why isn't `java.util.Arrays` available when I build this Blackberry app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the [package javadocs for `java.util`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/package-frame.html) from the Blackberry JDE site.  There is no `Arrays` class.

> Why isn't java.util.Arrays available when I build this Blackberry app?

Because Blackberry's Java implementation is based on Java Micro Edition (ME) not Java Standard Edition (SE).  (Specifically, it is described on the website as Mobile Information Device Profile (MIDP) compliant.)  Java ME class libraries are drastically cut down (compared to SE) to minimize runtime memory requirements.

Comment: Interestingly, [net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html) exists, but unfortunately it can't do fill on floats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that Blackberry JDE is [based on CLDC](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp), which is a mobile version of the desktop Java classpath and thus does not contain the class.